# iSCSI drive dropping connection

Tags: networking, network-share, storage-area-network, iscsi

I have a problem at the moment with one of our main shared folders.

The network speeds to this drive will suddenly slow right down and occasionally completely stop. The shared folder is an iSCSI drive stored on a SAN connected to one of our servers.

The backend of the SAN does not seem to be a problem and you can connect to the server with the drive attached and see the drive with no speed issues, however at the same time the share is inaccessible from anywhere else on the network. The NIC on the server is not reporting lots of traffic and you can remote onto the server with no issues.

I have detached the iSCSI and reattached it onto another server and have the same issues there. Not really sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this or how I can progress any further so any help would be great!

Comment: What operating system and network sharing protocols are you using? E.G. Windows, LInux, CIFS, NFS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if we could have some more information.
Logs...
Anyway, i had a similar problem.
On the host try those

```
netsh int tcp set global RSS=disabled
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled
```

and also try increasing
Receive(Default 256) and Transmit(Default 512) Buffers from advanced options of your network card. I made them 1024 and 2048

DO not do this on your NIC if you use it to connect to this server And Test those options ONLY with test data.